# discord.py - Is there a more pythonic way to create list of specified permissions?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py, append

**Code at the bottom**

My goal right now is basically to achieve creating a list of specified administrative permissions. I was able to do this but I'm wondering if there would be a more pythonic way to achieve this. As you may know already, discord.py permissions have lists like `guild_permissions`, or possibly `guild_permissions.text` but they don't have all the specified permissions that are all the administrative permissions that I want listed.

```
    list = []
    if member.guild_permissions.administrator:
        list.append("Administrator")
    if member.guild_permissions.manage_guild:
        list.append("Manage Server")
    if member.guild_permissions.manage_roles:
        list.append("Manage Roles")
    if member.guild_permissions.manage_channels:
        list.append("Manage Channels")
    if member.guild_permissions.manage_messages:
        list.append("Manage Messages")
    if member.guild_permissions.manage_webhooks:
        list.append("Manage Webhooks")
    if member.guild_permissions.manage_nicknames:
        list.append("Manage Nicknames") 
    if member.guild_permissions.manage_emojis:
        list.append("Manage Emojis")
    if member.guild_permissions.kick_members:
        list.append("Kick Members")
    if member.guild_permissions.ban_members:
        list.append("Ban Members")   
    if member.guild_permissions.mention_everyone:
        list.append("Mention Everyone")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Building off of @Chuaat's answer, you can also do this dynamically based on your list of the attribute names of interest:

```py
# the permissions to check
perms_to_check = [
    "administrator",
    "manage_guild",
    "manage_roles",
    "manage_channels",
    "manage_messages",
    "manage_webhooks",
    "manage_nicknames",
    "manage_emojis",
    "kick_members",
    "ban_members",
    "mention_everyone",
]

perm_list = discord.Permissions()
for perm in perms_to_check:
    if getattr(member.guild_permissions, perm):
        perm_list.update(**{perm: True})
```

Alternatively, once you know the permission value of interest, you can just do the same directly with some bit math

```py
# this is the value of Administrator | Manage Server | Manage Roles, ... etc.
perms_to_check_flags = 2013405246
perm_list = discord.Permissions(permissions=perms_to_check_flags & member.guild_permissions.value)
```

Comment: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'int' and 'Permissions'

Comment: I know what 2013405246 is in the permissions calculator, but what would & do?

Comment: @ineedhelp ah, sorry - forgot the `.value`, should work now

Comment: & is the bit-wise "and" operator in python.  Guild permission values are a type of "flag", a common pattern designed s.t. in binary, each 1 represents True or on and each 0 represents False or off. So when you run 2013405246 & member.guild_permissions.value you will get a new number s.t. each permission is True only when both the member has that permission AND it's one of the perms of interest.  In other words you get the value representing the intersection of the two, e.g. all your permissions of interest that the user has.

Comment: its ok, do you know how to re arrange the order? if you don't it's fine tho

Comment: @ineedhelp what do you mean rearrange the order?  The permission list is order-agnostic

Comment: so like basically if the list started with administrator, then manage guild, manage roles etc

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `permission` object provided by discord.py:

```
permissionList = discord.Permissions()
if member.guild_permissions.administrator:
    permissionList.update(administrator = True)
if member.guild_permissions.manage_guild:
    permissionList.update(manage_guild=True)
if member.guild_permissions.manage_roles:
    permissionList.update(manage_roles=True)
# ....
```

You then have a permission object which works the same way as for example `guild_permissions.text`

Comment: small typo, should be `permissionList.update(manage_roles=True)`